# Display "First Name" Data Based On First Letter

Tags: php, mysql, button, lookup

I am attempting to build a sign-in sheet that allows users to select the first letter of their first name, it would then grab all the users from the database and output them in a selectable list that then allows the user to choose their name and then inputs that they 'signed-in' into the database with a timestamp of when they clicked on their name.

Right now I'm stuck on the best way to have PHP go into the table, and do a look up on all the "First Names" that start with the letter that is chosen, and output the First_Name and Last_Name.

Example: I select "P" cause my name is "Pietro Aretino" it then gives me the output of every member whose First_Name starts with "P" and includes their last name as well. I find my name in the list "Pietro Aretino", I select that, it then sends stores my sign-in information in the database as well, which I suppose would be, my First/Last Name, and the timestamp.

But, I digress, for right now, I'm not sure how to have PHP do that lookup by First Name and then output the list

Right now I have every button A-Z labeled in military-alphabet (alpha, bravo etc.), when "A" is selected it runs the "alpha" function down below. Trying to figure out what to put into the "alpha" "bravo" "charlie" etc. functions that will make PHP go to the database and do a lookup and output the lists.

...here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*********";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "********** ";

//Create Connection
global $CONNECTION;
$CONNECTION = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check Connection
if ($CONNECTION->connect_error) {
    die("Connection To MySQL Database Failed With the Following Error: " . $connection->connect_error);
}
global $SQL; 
$SQL = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM ppSD_member_data";
global $RESULT; 
$RESULT = $CONNECTION->query($SQL);
if (isset($_POST['alpha'])) {
    alpha();
}
if (isset($_POST['bravo'])) {
    bravo();
}
if (isset($_POST['charlie'])) {
    charlie();
}
if (isset($_POST['delta'])) {
    delta();
}
if (isset($_POST['eko'])) {
    eko();
}
if (isset($_POST['foxtrot'])) {
    foxtrot();
}
if (isset($_POST['golf'])) {
    golf();
}
if (isset($_POST['hotel'])) {
    hotel();
}
if (isset($_POST['india'])) {
    india();
}
if (isset($_POST['juliet'])) {
    juliet();
}
if (isset($_POST['kilo'])) {
    kilo();
}
if (isset($_POST['lima'])) {
    lima();
}
if (isset($_POST['mike'])) {
    mike();
}
if (isset($_POST['november'])) {
    november();
}
if (isset($_POST['oscar'])) {
    oscar();
}
if (isset($_POST['papa'])) {
    papa();
}
if (isset($_POST['quebec'])) {
    quebec();
}
if (isset($_POST['romeo'])) {
    romeo();
}
if (isset($_POST['sierra'])) {
    sierra();
}
if (isset($_POST['tango'])) {
    tango();
}
if (isset($_POST['uniform'])) {
    uniform();
}
if (isset($_POST['victor'])) {
    victor();
}
if (isset($_POST['whiskey'])) {
    whiskey();
}
if (isset($_POST['xray'])) {
    xray();
}
if (isset($_POST['yankee'])) {
    yankee();
}
if (isset($_POST['zulu'])) {
    zulu();
}
echo <<<_END
<html>
    <head>
    <title>The Yard Members</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<h3>Please Select The Letter of Your First Name</h3>
<form method="post" action="display_members.php">
<input type="submit" name="alpha" id="name" value="A" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" name="bravo" id="name" value="B" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" name="charlie" id="name" value="C" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" name="name" id="name" value="D" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="E" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="F" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="G" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="H" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="I" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="J" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="K" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="L" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="M" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="N" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="O" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="P" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Q" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="R" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="S" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="T" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="U" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="V" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="W" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="X" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Y" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
<input type="submit" value="Z" style="height:75px; width:75px" />
</form>
</body>
</div>
</html>
_END;
function alpha() {
#while($row = $RESULT->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "This Is The Alpha Function";
    }
function bravo() {
    echo "This is the Bravo Function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
function charlie() {
    echo "This is the charlie function";
}
#}
/*if(array_key_exists('name', $_POST)){
    search();
}
function get_post($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
//Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Name: " . $row["first_name"]. " " . $row["last_name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No Members";
}
*/
$CONNECTION->close();
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what all this code is for, but it's a pretty simple SQL query to get all first names starting with a letter.  `SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE "P%"` would get all first_name's starting with P.

Comment: You have no question. But why do you want such a system? Not sure I see the benefit of it for the users. If you only have a handful of people with each letter then sure I can see a benefit. But if you type "A" and you have 100 names pop up, does it make it easier to find my name that to just type the rest?

Comment: umm interesting...  sounds like an "autocomplete" https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Yes it wouldnt be a big list, and I am going to try to put this on a tablet which would allow to swipe up and down fairly quickly to find your name in alphabetical order. And I'm sorry if it was not clear, my question was how to do a SQL lookup with PHP based on the "letter" selected and output the data in the table of first_names. So, If I choose "A" it will output a list of all users in the database whose first names start with "A". Etc.

Comment: @ficuscr Yes, but why use a system based autocomplete in theses days when every browser remembers your account name and optionally password. 20 years ago you would have been a hero.

Comment: @Andreas I hear ya! Preaching to the choir :) @PietroAretino keep doing this for 20 years and then please look back on this question. You will be forced to smile. As for answer: see Devons's comment about `WHERE LIKE`.

Comment: Devon, thank you I will try to see what I can do with that!
@ficuscr yes I have avoided "typing" because the environment this will be used on is dirty and things happen quickly. I wanted to be able to pull this web-page up on a tablet and have users get to their name in 2-clicks and swiping up and down on a list.

Comment: This code has ridiculous levels of duplication to the point where it's not only unmaintainable, it's unreadable as well. Don't hammer out hundreds of functions like this. Do take the time to express things in terms of data structures, and loops.

Comment: @tadman This is my first time learning programming and PHP, I'm sure its extremely inefficient. Still learning :/

Comment: I get that, and it's great you're trying to learn. You need to shift your thinking from copy-pasting endlessly and into describing things in terms of `array(...)` and such. Once you express things as data-structures you can do a lot more with a lot less code. It can be a bit tricky at first, but if you can think a step or two ahead about how your data is going to be used you can structure it in a way that's easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

As people are saying the code is <s>a bit</s> ridiculous. I'm just going to share this in the hopes of teaching you something. Not really looking to answer your question. In fact I'd suggest just deleting the question as I'm not sure how much utility it offers others. And "How to do a wildcard SQL search" is obviously a dupe question.

Anyway... Could be condensed down to something like:

```
//example.com?search_letter=A

$pattern = isset($_REQUEST('search_letter')) ? $_REQUEST('search_letter') : null;

if (empty($pattern)) {
    die('missing search paramter');
}

$pattern = $pattern . '%';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE ?';

$sth->execute([$pattern]);
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
```

What changes? What is the variable? A letter. Does how you render the output for `A` differ from how you will interpret and output `B`? No. So keep it DRY (Don't repeat yourself).